Implement Ridge Regression Equation for a Neural Network
I am trying to replicate the following equation in MATLAB to find the optimal output weight matrix of a neural network from training using ridge regression.
Output Weight Matrix of a Neural Network after Training using Ridge Regression:

This equation comes from the echo state network guide provided by Mantas Lukosevicius and can be found at: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319770153_A_practical_guide_to_applying_echo_state_networks (see page 11)
My attempt is below. I believe that the outer parenthesis (in red) makes this a non-traditional double summation, meaning the method presented by Voss (see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1694960-nested-loops-for-double-summation) cannot be followed. Note that y_i is a T by 1 vector and y_i_target is also a T by 1 vector. Wout_i is a N by 1 vector where N is the number of nodes in the neural network. I generate the three Ny by 1 vectors Wout_i,y_i,y_i_target for each i^th target training signal, where Ny is the number of training signals. The final output for Wout is a N by 1 vector, where each element in the vector is the optimal weight for each node in the network.
N = 100; % number of nodes in nerual network
Ny = 200; % number of training signals
T = 50; % time length of each training signal 
X = rand(N,T); % neural network state matrix
reg = 10^-4; % ridge regression coefficient
outer_sum = zeros(Ny,1);
for i = 1:Ny
y_i_target = rand(T,1); % training signal
Wout_i = ((X*X' + reg*eye(N)) \ (X*y_i_target)); 
Wouts{i} = Wout_i; % collected cell matrix of each Wout_i for each i^th target training signal
y_i = Wout_i'*X; % predicted signal 
inner_sum = sum(((y_i'-y_i_target).^2)+reg*norm(Wout_i)^2);
outer_sum(i) = inner_sum;
end
outer_sum = outer_sum.*(1/Ny);
[minval, minidx] = min(outer_sum);
Wout = cell2mat(Wouts(minidx));

My final answer for Wout is a N by 1 as it should be, but I am uncertain in my answer. I am particularly unsure whether or not I have done the double summation and arg min with respect to Wout operations correctly. Is there any way to validate my answer?
Solution:
I tried out another method/attempt as shown below:
N = 100; % number of nodes in nerual network
Ny = 200; % number of training signals
T = 50; % time length of each training signal 
X = rand(N,T); % neural network state matrix
reg = 10^-4; % ridge regression coefficient
MSE = zeros(Ny,1);
for i = 1:Ny
y_i_target = rand(T,1); % training signal
Wout_i = ((X*X' + reg*eye(N)) \ (X*y_i_target)); % Eq. 9 from Luko et al.
Wouts{i} = Wout_i; % collected cell matrix of each Wout_i for each i^th target training signal
y_i = Wout_i'*X; % predicted signal 
MSE(i) = (1/T)*sum((y_i'-y_i_target).^2); % mean square error
end
[minval, minidx] = min(MSE);
Wout = cell2mat(Wouts(minidx));

I believe this attempt is better than the first, but I am not sure if it’s right still.
As highlighted by BillBokeey, the desired equation is simply an iterative version of equation 9 from Luko et al. To conduct training, one must apply Eq. 9 to each target signal in the the training data set and choose the resulting W_out that minimizes mean square error (MSE).
Final Update:
I am still looking for some validation of my second solution. I am particularly concerned that I am cherry picking the best Wout_i N by 1 vector that minimizes MSE and effectively ignoring all the other Wout_i vectors.

Your outer_sum should be initialised to zeros(Ny,1) so it doesn't grow inside the loop, also you never calculate the sum of outer_sum? Additional context on the origins of that equation might help with validation, as well as example inputs and their respective expected outputs so we can actually run the code, otherwise this is not a [mcve]. Aside: this is a cross-post from MathWorks Answers

I've added inputs and outputs. The example runs now. I never calculate outer_sum since using the min() function only makes sense if outer_sum is a vector, not a single number.  I am quite confused on how to calculate the outer_sum and properly take the minimum of outer_sum with respect to Wout_i. @Wolfie

Thanks for the extra edits, I haven't had chance to read your linked paper but I assume the min can't make the sum redundant, otherwise there would be no point having that summation in the equation

Got it. If you have the time the ride regression method begins on page 11. @Wolfie

Are you sure Wout should be a vector? It would make a lot more sense if it was a matrix. (It actually is : Wout ∈ RNy×(1+Nu+Nx) , page 4)

So this is actually a minimization problem right? You are looking for a matrix Wout ∈ RNy×(1+Nu+Nx), such that your sum is minimal

Yes. You are right.  @BillBokeey

Actually, you do not have to solve this equation to calculate Wout. This equation is only there to illustrate what equation 27.9 of the paper actually does.

What page is equation 27.9 on? I think you mean equation 9? @BillBokeey

taking the min of the Wout_i is not what the equation says. The argmin in the equation means you should find a matrix Wout such as the double sum is minimal. This matrix Wout is, for a given regression coefficient, exactly the solution of Eq. 9.

I see. So Eq. 9 is literally numerically equivalent to Eq. 11 (the equation in question)? @BillBokeey

Yes, exactly! Eq. 11 is a more "graphical" version of Eq. 9!

@BillBokeey I love overcomplicating things. Thank you Bill.
